# How to implement percentile in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, percentile

Can anyone please tell me ,how to implement Percentile in Hive?
I tried with percentile function,but not able to get the expected result.
Example code will greatly help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`percentile`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) function, as per the product documentation:

> Returns the exact pth percentile of a column in the group (does not work with floating point types). p must be between 0 and 1. NOTE: A true percentile can only be computed for integer values. Use `PERCENTILE_APPROX` if your input is non-integral.

If you are not able to get 'expected result' then your going to add a lot more detail to your question, as in what is the data, your query, and the expected result.