# How to implement percentile in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, percentile

I have a table like this in hive

```
user_id     no.of game_plays
u1           52
u2           190
u10          166
u9           100
u3           90
u4           44
u5           21
u7           10
u8           5
```

Above is just a very small sample of data.

So, the total game_plays are **678**

I want to calculate the users in each group like below

```
who contribute to top 33.3% of total game_plays and 
who contribute to between 33.3% and 66.6% of total game_plays 
who contribute to bottom 33.3% of total game_plays
```

Basically, split the data into 3 group like above and get top 20 users from each group.

I know the logic of how to implement in BigQuery like....get the percentile value ordered by game_plays and then put a case statement in the above query and rank using game_plays in each group and select rank <=20

which give the result I wanted.

I don't know how to implement this kind of thing in hive.

I have gone through the below pages, but not getting an idea

[How to implement percentile in Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146395/how-to-implement-percentile-in-hive)

[How to calculate median in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863139/how-to-calculate-median-in-hive)

And have gone through the functions link below,

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types

I know I have to percentile function...but knot sure exactly how I implement.

Below is the code I have tried,

```
select a.user_id,a.game_plays, percentile(a.game_plays,0.66) as percentile
from (
select user_id, sum(game_plays) as game_plays
from game_play_table
where data_date = '2019-06-01' 
group by user_id) a
```

I know the above code doesn't give exact give output, but after writing an outer query over it....I can get the output I wanted....but the above query output is itself very different.

Can anyone please help ???

Answer (score 0):

> You could use **"case"** to calculate the percentile

```
select user_id,game_plays ,
case when (game_plays * (100 /678)) > 33.3 then 'top 33.3%'
when (game_plays * (100 /678)) > 33.3) and (game_plays * (100 /678)) < 66.6) then 'between 33.3% and 66.6%'
when (game_plays * (100 /678)) < 33.3) then 'less then 33.3%'
end as percentile 
from game_play_table
where data_date = '2019-06-01' 
group by user_id
```

Comment: Hi M.achaibou, I think the above puts every thing in 'less then 33.3%'  unless until any single record having a value that contributes more than 33.3% then it changes the bucket.....just to be more clear....I want users who cumulatively make the top 33.3% of game_plays....did you understand the difference ?